# Only insert Google adsense on certain screen size?

Tags: javascript, adsense

I'm building a small website including Adsense blocks. In the mobile CSS the div including the ad will be hidden (display:none;). To prevent false ad impressions I want to prevent the Adsense code from executing leaving the ad div empty if the browser size is smaller than 999px.

When looking on Google I can only find information about the new responsible ads, but I don't want that. Instead I'm just looking for the right js code to check upon page load and then either show or now show the ad.

Right now I have tried this:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- website_index_large_rect -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></ins>
<script>
  width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  if (width > 999) {
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  }
</script>
```

But this only prevents the push thingy from executing. Will this cause false impressions? Does it comply with TOS?

Is there a better way to wrap the whole thing and prevent it from executing if the browser is too small ?

Comment: @adeneo - with a statement like that, I think a link to the exact part of their policy that you are violating is required.

Comment: @Adam - any modification to the adsense code, for instance trying to insert it dynamically or with iframes, is a violation of the TOS.

Comment: @adeneo - that's not a link. Nor do I see that on either of the following two ad placement policy pages - https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?utm_source=aso&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=ww-ww-et-asfe_, https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295. Not saying you are incorrect, I just think you need to show your source when making such a statement.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I see that you are allowed to modify the adsense code as you see fit, within the following guideline: `Publishers are permitted to make modifications to the AdSense ad code so long as those modifications do not artificially inflate ad performance or harm advertisers.`

Comment: @Adam: And that's what I'm going for here. I want to edit the code so that it prevents inflated ad performance. Because if the code gets executed the ad will be inserted to a hidden div.

But I'm not happy with my solution, because the *.js file still gets called. I'd rather have something wrap the whole thing and either run it or not. Any ideas?

Comment: @JasonTS - I don't think what you are doing is against their ToS and I haven't found any information to the contrary. Keep in mind that you can embed the script tag dynamically as well based on width. Also, the `push` method is actually what is serving the ad/creating the impression, not just embedded the google-supplied js, so it appears that the code you have posted should work fine and be within their ToS. Are you having problems with it?

Comment: @Adam No problems, but I'm scared it might cause trouble. Isn't there an easy way to not embed the whole script tag just to make sure? I was hoping there was some way to wrap the if statement around the script tag. Unfortunately I'm not fluent in JS.

Comment: @"_I don't think what you are doing is against their ToS_" - It is not obvious, but there is very serious issue with that code, and it is **not** safe for use. More info here: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/xdk9h3yAxS0/FhM8Zl_sDNsJ